# Not able to run docker image in GCP VM instance created via terraform

Tags: docker, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create a GCP VM instance that will run a docker image using Terraform script. After applying the Terraform changes, I can see that the VM instance was created successfully but when I try to list the running docker images with the "docker ps" command, it results in an error "-bash: docker: command not found".
Any idea where I am going wrong? Here is my script code:

```
module "gce-container" {
  source = "terraform-google-modules/container-vm/google"
  version = "~> 2.0"

  container = {
    name = "nginx"
    image = "gcr.io/cloud-marketplace/google/nginx1:latest"
  }

  restart_policy = "Always"
}

// Create VM instance with docker image:
resource "google_compute_instance" "agent1" {
  name         = var.agentname
  machine_type = "e2-small"
  zone         = "${var.region}-a"
  depends_on   = [google_compute_address.static1]
  network_interface {
    network    = google_compute_network.vpc.name
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.subnet.name
    access_config {
      nat_ip = google_compute_address.static1.address
    }
  }
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "rhel-cloud/rhel-7"
    }
  }

   **metadata = {
    // This should spawn a docker image after the vm instance is created successfully.
    gce-container-declaration = module.gce-container.metadata_value
  }**
}
```

Comment: Does the instance come with Docker preinstalled?

Comment: Don't think so but when I create the same VM instance from the browser, everything works. Probably that is the difference. Might be google is choosing automatically docker supported boot image when I go via the browser. let me check.

Comment: ...It doesn't exactly sound like they are the same machines, but if you're sure here are several debug options: 1 - Run it from the browser again, and run `which docker`, then try executing it with the full path and not the `docker` command. This is likely to be in `/usr/bin/docker` 2 - Are you sure you are running as the same user both in the browser and in the above? I'm referring to the user running the `docker` command. 3 - You can try installing docker before running `docker ps`, or check if it is installed.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Incorrect boot disk was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the incorrect image for this task. Changing the boot disk worked for me. I can run docker commands now :)

```
image = "cos-cloud/cos-73-11647-217-0"
```